# How to prove that $S_n = n^{2}$?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, analytic-number-theory

If $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$ and for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we define the set $A_{n}=\left\{k \in \mathbb{N}: \{\frac{n}{k}\}  \geq \frac{1}{2} \right\}$. Then how can I try to calculate the sum: $ S_{n}=\sum_{k \in A_{n}} \varphi(k)$ where $\varphi$ is the Euler's totient function.
I've tried calculating the sum by hand for integers $1\leq n\leq 10$ and noticed that $S_{n} = n^{2}$ for these, but other than this, I have not found any other patterns.

Comment: I dk. I suggest you try $S_n$ for some larger $n.$  E.g. $ A_{17}=\{2,3,9,10,11\}$  and $S_{17}=1+2+6+4+10 =23.$

Comment: Well if I am not wrong, $A_{17}$ = {2, 3, 6, 9, 10, 11, 18,...,34}

Comment: Sorry. I forgot that $k>n$ is allowed. Did you calculate $S_{17}$?

Comment: That is really a lot of calculation, I only tried until 10 and I believe the statement is true.

Comment: Well I had tried 1+2+2+6+4+10+6+18+8+12+10+22+8+20+12+18+12+28+8+30+16+20+16 = 289 = $17^{2}$

Comment: Since hand calculation is exhausting, I typed some Mathematica code and found it to be true for $n \le 1000$. But a computer verification is hardly substantive enough for an answer.

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshiner. True.But it's a good motivation for suspecting that there may be an elementary proof.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet True. But I have no idea what sort of proof strategy one might employ for this.

Comment: With some more work I have been able to verify the conjecture in C++ for the first 10,000 cases. Pretty sure this thing is correct.